# Flash crossdomain multipart POST not working?

Tags: flash, xmlhttprequest, crossdomain.xml

I'm using [moxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie) as an XHR2 polyfill to issue a crossdomain POST file upload, using a `FormData` to construct a multipart request containing a  `File` object from a `FileInput`.

Using the HTML5 runtime, the request is successful and the file is uploaded. However, when using the Flash runtime, `crossdomain.xml` is successfully requested, but the request soon hits `readyState` 4 with a `status` of 0, suggesting the request was cancelled because it was an invalid cross-domain request.

The [`crossdomain.xml` spec](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf) mentions nothing about request methods. A quick search on the moxie Github turns up [this issue](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/issues/38), which seems to have been resolved, although the issue is still open. Unlike in the issue, I'm not seeing *any* request go through after `crossdomain.xml`.

The code to send the request:

```
var xhr = new moxie.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.bind('load', function() {
  if(this.status === 200) {
    // yay!
  } else {
    // boo!
  }
});

var form = new moxie.FormData();
form.append('file', file); // file is a moxie.File from a FileInput

xhr.send(form);
```

My crossdomain.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Is the polyfill kicking in or are you using the native XHR object?

Comment: Browser is Opera 20, I'm forcing moxie to use Flash by setting `moxie.Runtime.order = 'flash,html5';`. Flash is definitely loading, as I'm using moxie for the file picker as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the AS3 documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29):

> In Flash Player 10 and later, if you use a multipart Content-Type (for example "multipart/form-data") that contains an upload (indicated by a "filename" parameter in a "content-disposition" header within the POST body), the POST operation is subject to the security rules applied to uploads:
>
> - The POST operation must be performed in response to a user-initiated action, such as a mouse click or key press.
> - If the POST operation is cross-domain (the POST target is not on the same server as the SWF file that is sending the POST request), the target server must provide a URL policy file that permits cross-domain access.

The reason my request is failing is the first bullet point, since my POST isn't done "response to a user-initiated action, such as a mouse click".

Quite how moxie expects me to do this I'm not sure, as all their (scarce) documentation indicates that cross-platform multipart uploads are possible.